# errorBody() Expected BEGIN_ARRAY

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, httpresponse

I'm trying to convert the `errorBody` into my `RegistrationResponse` but it is always throwing an `Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT`

**`RegistrationResponse`**

```
data class RegistrationResponse(
    val status: Boolean,
    val errors: List<RegistrationBody>
)
```

**`RegistrationBody`**

```
data class RegistrationBody(
    val lastname: String,
    val firstname: String,
    val middlename: String
)
```

**My Converter**

```
if (it is HttpException) {
    if (it.code() == 400) {
        // Bad Request
        val errorConverter: Converter<ResponseBody, RegistrationResponse>? = retro?.responseBodyConverter(RegistrationResponse::class.java, arrayOfNulls<Annotation>(0))
        Log.i("TAG", "${errorConverter?.convert(it.response().errorBody())}")
    }
}
```

**My Expected Output**

```
{                       
    status: false,                  
    errors: {                   
        lastName: "The last name is required.",             
        firstName: "The first name is required.",               
        middleName: "The middle name is required.",             
    }                   
}
```

did I miss something in the code?

I also try the

```
val errorConverter: Converter<ResponseBody, List<RegistrationResponse>>? = retro?.responseBodyConverter(RegistrationResponse::class.java, arrayOfNulls<Annotation>(0))
```

still the error is `Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT

**`RegistrationBody`** is **OBJECT** not **ARRAY**.

You should use

```
    data class RegistrationResponse(
    val status: Boolean,
    val errors: RegistrationBody
)
```

Comment: o god, I'm stuck here for almost 4 hours.  I did not notice that 'coz I'm focusing to the whole response. Thank you.